# Pygame some methods aren't working properly (collidepoint and get_rect)

Tags: collision-detection, pygame, mouse

I'm making a game menu in Pygame, consider the following block of code:

```
pygame.init()
...
exit_button = pygame.image.load(r'/home/salem/Documents/MyGame/exit_b.png').convert_alpha()
cursor = pygame.image.load(r'/home/salem/Documents/MyGame/clicker.png').convert_alpha()
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
x, y = mouse
cursor_x = x + cursor.get_width() / 2
cursor_y = y + cursor.get_height() / 2

while 1:
...
menu.blit(exit_button, (10, 555))
menu.blit(cursor, (cursor_x, cursor_y))
if exit_button.get_rect(x=10, y=555).collidepoint(mouse):
    exit()
pygame.display.update()
...
```

I'm experiencing some problems with the `pygame.mouse` module and `get_rect` method. They're not working correctly.

If I get the mouse position on the exit_button image while the script is running, nothing happens and it doesn't exit!

Furthermore, for some reason, the cursor's image is not being displayed, I can only see the system's cursor while moving the mouse though it's remarkably different from the cursor's image. (the system's cursor is black while the other one is white)
At first, I thought they could be merged together, so to check that, I changed the cursor's coordinates but still the same result!

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't seem to ever update `mouse` or `cursor_x` or `cursor_y`, is that representative of your real running code? You should also consider always sharing a minimal verifiable example of your issue.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 yeah that's my real code

Comment: In fact, I barely work with these methods, that's why I'm messing up with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not ever updating the cursor position so the code will only check collisions at whatever the cursor position happens to be immediately after initialization.

If you want to check against the real position of the cursor, you need to call `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` again each iteration of the game loop, and of course then recalculate `cursor_x` and `cursor_y` using the new updated mouse position to make sure your cursor image is rendererd in the correct position.

Comment: Oh yeah that's true! I can't realize how didn't I pay attention to that ! hahaha thanks !